# click link submit form simulate specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an html form with a table and 2 submit buttons

```
<input type="image" name="button1" value="First Button" src="some_image.png">
<input type="image" name="button2" value="Second Button" src="some_image.png">
```

I have a link that I would like to simulate a click on the first button

```
<a name="link_to_button" value="First Button" href="#" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit();">test submit</a>
```

I would like to have 2 links, one that simulates clicking on each submit button so that I can distinguish on the server which one was clicked.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could give your buttons inputs IDs, (such as imgBtn1 and imgBtn2) then you could change your Anchor code to:

```
<a name="link_to_button" value="First Button" href="#" onclick="$('#imgBtn1').click();">test submit 1</a>

<a name="link_to_button" value="Second Button" href="#" onclick="$('#imgBtn2').click();">test submit 2</a>
```